# CSV outputs to one cell

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

Sorry if my code is awful, I've just started learning Python.

I'm scraping data from a HTML file and trying to write to a CSV.

The problem is that it is writing all the content to one cell.

```
for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='players-table'):
    for headers in soup.find_all('thead'):
        for y in headers.findAll('th'):
              [csvHeader.append(i) for i in y if y.getText() != '']


counter = 0

myfile = open('/Users/andrew/Documents/Projects/Football Data/ppi.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',',  lineterminator='\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
c = csv.writer(myfile)
c.writerow(csvHeader)



for table in soup.find_all('table', class_='players-table'):
    for headers in soup.find_all('tbody'):
        for rows in headers.findAll('tr'):
            for x in rows.findAll('td'):
                if x.getText() !='':
                    csvRows_temp.append(x.getText().replace('\n                            ','').replace('\n                        ',''))
                    counter +=1
                if counter == 13:
                    myList = [','.join(csvRows_temp).encode('utf8').strip()]
                    csvRows_temp.append('\n')
                    c.writerow(myList)
                    csvRows_temp[:] = []
                    myList[:] = []
                    counter = 0
```

The output is this: 
[image]

How can I make it write to each cell instead of passing it to a single cell on each row?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you don't mind where did you find the HTML file you want to scrape ? I am interested in football data, too.

Comment: evil_inside, http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/players/ea-sports-player-performance-index.html

EA provide a Player Performance Index for the Barclay's Premier League. If you change the results per page to anything other than 20 and then change paramItemsPerPage from the URL to 999 you will get a complete list of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
myList = [','.join(csvRows_temp).encode('utf8').strip()]
```

creates a list with exactly one element, a string with several commas in it.

Try:

```
myList = csvRows_temp
```

or perhaps, if you think you need the text processing:

```
myList = [x.encode('utf8').strip() for x in csvRows_temp]
```

Comment: I did need the text processing, the data contained quite a lot of unicode characters. The last example you gave me worked like a dream! Thanks Rob.